# Is this grammatical to say 'the surpassing all others platform'?

Tags: clauses, participle-clauses

Is this grammatical to say

> Twitter had the chance to become a true global public square, the surpassing all others free-speech platform of the digital age

instead of

> Twitter had the chance to become a true global public square, the preeminent free-speech platform of the digital age.

Comment: you need an s, but really google will tell you that.

Comment: what does it mean?

Comment: Your sentence would be better as "Twitter had the chance to become a true global public square, thus surpassing all other free-speech platforms in the digital age."

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can join together any number of words to make a long, compound adjective, eg:

> surpassing-all-others, free-speech platform

but it's often inelegant and wordy. "Preeminent" is better because it says all that in a single word.

Comment: Do I have to put dashes between words?

Comment: It's not *required*, but it can help to connect the related words into a more readable series.  Otherwise it can be difficult to know which words modify which other words.